# Google Data Studio Hide Data on Line Chart

Tags: looker-studio

Can I hide data number on line chart to make it only show the trend instead of the actual data?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the Axis, switching from a [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) Chart to a **Sparkline** Chart does the trick (or manually remove the required labels and Axis from the **Style Tab** of the Time Series Chart).

To prevent interactions with the Chart, one approach is to add a transparent [Shape](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6289367) over the Chart.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/61eabc79-bdae-4b38-8ed8-56055d78da47) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]